# use Elasticsearch Ranged queries in grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I have a elasticsearch range query like this

```
curl 'localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty' -d '
{
"query": {
    "range" : {
        "total" : {
            "gte" :174,
            "lte" :180
             }  
         }
     }
}'
```

I need to use this query in grafana for my graph. i am trying to add this as a part of the Lucene query. but i am not able to find the desired result. can anyone help.

Comment: i need suggestions on using the query in Grafana and not in elasticsearch. thaks

Answer (score 4):

If "total" is a field, you can do something like this in Lucene:

```
total:[174 TO 180]
```

reference: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

First off I think you may be missing the document type from the request URL, should look like so:

```
http://localhost:9200/[INDEX]/[TYPE]/_search?pretty
```

Second, I've looked at previous answers providing detailed examples of range filtering and the query should work just fine like so

```
{
    "query": 
        {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "total": {
                        "gte": 174,
                        "lte": 180    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I would like to quote few changes on what you told. First of all giving the type is not mandatory. it is required only when you want your search to be specific for one particular type. Second, the query which you gave will work fine when i query it in Elasticsearch, But i want to make this query work in Grafana